# Why we need hypersurface to solve initial value problem in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, causality, differential-equations

Almost all in general relativity book to tackle the initial value problem there we need the concept of hypersurface and another concept like future or past domain of dependence.

My question is what is the motivation for introducing the concept of hypersurface in order to solve initial value problem in general relativity?

Comment: How else would you propose to specify the initial values?

Comment: Stephane rollandin Yes but not completely, will you please provide me some similar answers that helps me a lot.